# Intuitive explanation of Gaussian Process Regression

Tags: stochastic-processes, gaussian-process, intuition, kriging

How would you intuitively explain the idea behind Gaussian Process Regression to someone unfamiliar with stochastic processes?  Especially  the point where you discuss modeling covariance, choice of kernel functions etc?

I'm familiar with Gaussian Process' but I'm having a hard time explaining them to someone without sufficient mathematical background and for that I need a new perspective.

Comment: In my opinion you should explain like in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R-NUdqxKjos&t=1514s (min 24:00). Also kernels are the measure the similarities between the points of the dataset.(This is what I understood)